# Is there a way to see how much data is being inserted into a database during given time periods using only SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

Is there is a way within SQL Server Management Studio alone to see how much data was inserted into a database over a time period?  There are specific tools for this kind of tracking, but I was just curious if that kind of information was available to query or see in a report within SSMS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways you could find how much data was inserted in a table by only using SQL Server

1. Triggers - You can define triggers that will store the information in a separate table for each row inserted with additional information like time of insert and inserted by which login, etc.
2. fn_dblog - If your database is in full recovery mode, you can look inside your log file (ldf) and see all transactions that have happened. Of course this will be removed after a log backup where all this information is then written into the log backup file. to access it, you can use fn_dbdumplog. To understand the content is however an otherworldly task and usually third party softwares use this function to decode the data and present to you in a nice way. [This guy](https://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/) however, wrote a stored proc that can decode fn_dblog and give you the deleted rows. very useful stored procedure for using data recovery.But minor alter can give you inserted as well. However, he has yet to write for fn_dbdumplog (maybe he wrote but hasn't shared publicly)so you can only see ones that are still in ldf and not beyond using his sp.
3. keeping a timestamp in the table itself by design - Every-time a new row is inserted, by database design, if your insert query includes a getdate function and is storing this in table along with rest of data, you can always know about all rows inserted in table during a specified time range.

Comment: XEvents possibly also